# How can I run pigpiod and gpsd on the same machine?

Tags: uart, pigpio

I've now got an Ultimate GPS board attached to the UART, and use both the GPIO pins, and the SPI interface by addressing the pigpio library. The pigpiod docs tell me that pigpiod would control the UART, too, but then it would probably interfere with the gpsd, which already controls the UART.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pigpio can control the UART - but it only does so if you ask it to, by making a C call to [serOpen()](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#serOpen) (or it's equivalent from Python, pigs, etc).

So the solution is don't use pigpio to control the UART, that will leave the UART available for GPSD to control,

Comment: You meant [serial_open()](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pdif2.html#serial_open), dindn't you?

Comment: Yes, serial_open() is the name of the function used by the Python module and the pigpiod I/F C library.  Both eventually call the underlying C serOpen() function.